# SubSonic doesn't map stored procedures in packages

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic

I've used SubSonic for MS SQL and it works wonderfully!!!!
Does anyone know what's with Oracle's SPS in Packages?
Please help. Need to deliver a func very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle packages aren't supported. I'm not sure there are plans to support them any time soon.